# Rotating a vector by a quaternion

Tags: xna, directx, vector, quaternion

I am trying to rotate a direction vector (0,0,1,0) by a rotation quaternion in DirectX.

From what understanding, to rotate the vector you must do

```
NewVector = rotQuaternion * Vector * inverse(rotQuaternion)
```

In directX11, I am testing out the algorithm above using an identity quaternion.

```
XMVECTOR qIdentity = XMQuaternionIdentity();
XMVECTOR inverse = XMQuaternionInverse(qIdentity);
XMVECTOR test = qIdentity * XMVectorSet(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f) * inverse;
```

My new test vector should just be (0,0,1,0), however it is completely zeroed out, and I am not exactly sure why or if I multiplied it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quaternions do not multiply component-wise like vectors, thus the `*` operator must not be used here.

```
XMVECTOR qIdentity = XMQuaternionIdentity();
XMVECTOR inverse = XMQuaternionInverse(qIdentity);

XMVECTOR test = XMQuaternionMultiply(qIdentity,
                                     XMVectorSet(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
test = XMQuaternionMultiply(test, inverse);
```